# best way to Compare 2 resultsets

Tags: java

Im trying to compare 2 resultsets..

There are 2 results sets rs and rs1.They are fetched from the same table running in different instance of DB

ie rs has the value of "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" from instance 1
ie rs1 has the value of "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" from instance 2

is there way to compare the 2 resultsets without iterating (while(rs.next()) through each row in resultset..

is it possible to just find the difference between rs and rs1..

i tried iterating and comparing some columns ..also tried compareto ...but the system performance is slow..the tables have min of 60K records with 20 columsn..so im looking for help to come up with best comparison

Thanks

Comment: I do not think that there is a way of comparing, except iterating through both of them. We may help if you can explain what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @dj aqeel: I think you're wrong

Answer (score 2):

Here are several approaches i can think of :

1. Solve it through SQL statement IN and NOT IN
2. Java's Set has several built-in method like containsAll(Collection), retainAll(Collection), removeAll(Collection). You can employ them solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Hendra Jaya.. the Dbs donot have dbo enabled , so i cannot use IN and Not IN...though will try sets..

Comment: I tried sets , im able to get the difference between the 2 resultset , however after this i will have to create a excel report.The values are availble in it.next()(iterator) but cannt be split for each cell...how can this be done ??